# Attach at runtime a wrapper to all existing event handlers

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I am currently in deep need of logging for an existing application, and can't afford to add the level of logging I expect directly into the code. As a workaround, I'd be happy to have a certain amount of logging done each time an event is fired.

I am considering a solution where I could, at runtime, parse the whole application to wrap all event-to-handler bindings with event-to-wrapper-to-handler; and, ideally, unwrap them at runtime too. In Pseudo-code, this would be:

```
IDictionary<Event, Action<object, EventArgs>) originalBindings = ...;

public void SetWrapBindings()
{
   var allBindingsToReplace = Assembly.GetAssembly().GETALLEVENTS()
      .Where(eventInfo => eventInfo.GetOtherMethods().Any());

   foreach(var binding in allBindingsToReplace)
   {
     binding.event -= binding.handler;
     binding.event += HandlerWrapper;
     originalBindings.Add(binding.event, binding.handler);
   }

}

public static void HandlerWrapper(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do some logging
    try
    {
       var handler = originalBindings.TryGetValue(/* something */);
       handler.Invoke(o, e);
    }
    // Do more logging
}
```

In this bunch of pseudo-code there are lots of steps I was not able to write, possibly because I didn't find the correct API use, but maybe also because some operation in that is theoretically impossible (in which case I'd love to know why). These are:

- Iterating over all events of the application (this would probably be easy)
- Identifying a good key for my IDictionary
- At each step, get the relevant information from the context

Of course, binding one extra handler to each existing event (pre/post-executing a routine without really wrapping the handler) would help, but executing the real handler inside a try-catch is a big nice to have.

Any partial answer is still greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems the most seen example for AOP!!! Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for non-invasive system-wide logging, you'd be better off using an aspect-oriented programming framework like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).  [This page](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging) provides a decent jumping off point for what you're looking for.

**Edit:**  To add to this, look at implementing an `EventInterceptionAspect` if you really do just want to know when any event is raised.  Again, the PostSharp blog is a good source of info, and [this article](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-11-e28093-Interception-e28093-Part-3.aspx) shows an implementation of this aspect that does simple stdout logging of adding, removing, and invoking.